# Can not access chart series datalabels in excel and add in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel, charts, add-in

I am trying to write JavaScript code to generate an excel add-in, using Visual Studio 2015. The aim of the code is to generate a chart and add labels (from text value within the spreadsheet) at specific locations on the chart.  The problem with the code I have written seems to be that the chart `datalabels` are undefined and can not find a method to access text fields within the spreadsheet for the labels.

```
var sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
var sourceData = sheet.getRange("C3:D6");
var chart = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheetName).charts.add("xyscatter", sourceData, "auto");
    chart.datalabels.visible = true;
    chart.datalabels.position = "top";
    chart.datalabels.ShowSeriesName = true;
```

Error:

```
 Exception was thrown at ……
 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'visible' of  undefined or null reference
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: `dataLabels` - js is case-sensitive.  https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/chart.md  Edit - although the example uses the lower-case name...

Comment: Thanks Tim, changing the case did fix the error.  My mistake was copying and pasting code from the 'Office Dev Center'.(http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/chartdatalabels).

Comment: Yes that doesn't inspire much confidence...